# Git SSH Error Bad File Number

Tags: git, ssh

I'm setting up a git server with the git guide for it (http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).
So I made a user git on the Ubuntu server, and i put the ssh key of my pc in the `authorized_keys` file.

I made a repo on the git account in `/repos/test/test.git`
When i try to clone from the windows pc with

```
git clone git@196.168.0.114:/repos/test/test.git
```

it gives me this:

```
Cloning into 'test'...
ssh: connect to host 196.168.0.114 port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Also i have a password on the git account

.ssh chmod 700 by the git account

authorized_keys chmod 600 by the git account

Comment: What are the permissions of the folder `.ssh` on the server? What are the permissions of the `authorized_keys` file?

Comment: .ssh on the server is chmod 700, authorized keys is chmod 600. I did the chmods with the git account

Answer (score 0):

From the [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/error-bad-file-number/):

> This error usually means you were unable to connect to the server. Often this is caused by firewalls and proxy servers.

Please check your firewall settings on Windows and on the Linux client.

Try `ssh -vvv git@196.168.0.114`

If you see this in the output:

```
 [196.168.0.114] port 22. debug1: connect to address 196.168.0.114 port 22: Attempt to connect timed out without establishing a connection
```

then there is a firewall inside or between your two computers which swallows packets.

Comment: I turned off the firewalls on both windows and the ubuntu server (on ubuntu like this: $ sudo iptables -X
$ sudo iptables -t nat -F
$ sudo iptables -t nat -X
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -F
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -X
$ sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT) And it still gives the same error

Comment: Try `ssh -v -v -v git@196.168.0.114` and look for problems in the output.

Comment: ssh -v -v -v git@196.168.0.114

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to 196.168.0.114 [196.168.0.114] port 22.

debug1: connect to address 196.168.0.114 port 22: Attempt to connect timed out without establishing a connection

ssh: connect to host 196.168.0.114 port 22: Bad file number

Comment: Connection times out -> Firewall problem. there must be another firewall between you and 192.168.0.114. Can you ping the server?

Comment: Yes i can, average ping is 2ms

Comment: Also have a look at `ufw` to configure the Ubuntu firewall correctly. See https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/firewall.html

Comment: This article contains a few tips to debug network related problems: http://www.unixlore.net/articles/troubleshooting-ssh-connections.html